# How to make ListTile fixed height?

Tags: flutter, listtile

I want to draw some ListTile with the same height, but I can't do it anyway.

[image]

I don't want to draw a custom layout myself because ListTile contains a lot of other features, like accessibility, slipping, tap effect, etc.

I tried wrapping it with `Container` with `height` and `Alignment.center`, but the waterwave effect didn't cover all the widget.

I was confused. Does anyone have another way? ️

sample code:

```dart
ListView(
  children: const [
    ListTile(leading: Icon(Icons.stop), title: Text('one line')),
    Divider(height: 1),
    ListTile(leading: Icon(Icons.stop), title: Text('two line'), subtitle: Text('aaa')),
    Divider(height: 1),
    ListTile(leading: Icon(Icons.stop), title: Text('one line')),
    Divider(height: 1),
  ],
)
```

Comment: how about adding `, subtitle: Text('')`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap the ListTile with Container or Sizedbox and then give height to it.

Comment: This will place all the elements in ListTile on top of the Container, and wrap it with Center will also be the problem of incomplete inkWell coverage :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Move your "subtitle" widget into your "title", and wrap them with a Column, and don't forget to add some style;

(In this case, the first step is enough. For more complicated situations, you may need some more steps.)

2. Wrap your Column as well as other Text with a SizedBox which has a fixed height.
3. Add a `minVerticalPadding` property to the ListTiles to adjust all the padding.

Here is my code:

```dart
ListView(
  children: const [
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.stop),
      title: Text('one line'),
    ),
    Divider(height: 1),
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.stop),
      title: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('two line'),
          Text('aaa'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Divider(height: 1),
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.stop),
      title: Text('one line'),
    ),
    Divider(height: 1),
  ],
)
```